# How to get current logger date format pattern in log4j2?

Tags: java, log4j2

I want to get my current logger format pattern dynamically, how can I get it?

Comment: I’m having a hard time imagining a use case for this.

Comment: Not still, I have a use for it… please don’t judge 

Comment: Leonhard has the right idea.  You can use the Configuration to get the Appenders, look for a PatternLayout in each Appender, then parse each pattern and look for a DatePatternConverter.  But I’m pretty sure that whatever you’re trying to do, there’s probably a better way to do it.

Comment: I’ve tried that, but, when I get the relevant appender, I can’t get from it it’s date patternLayout

Comment: Why not?  What is preventing you from doing it?

Comment: @VGR the closest I can get is the pattern of the hole message as `String`, and not the concrete one created (probably) via `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.DatePatternConverter#createFormatter`

Comment: Use PatternLayout’s [createPatternParser](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/layout/PatternLayout.html#createPatternParser-org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configuration-) method to create a parser.  PatternParser has methods that return a list of PatternFormatters.  Check each PatternFormatter for a converter which is a DatePatternConverter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious what the use case is. Try this out. :)

```
final LoggerContext ctx = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
final Configuration config = ctx.getConfiguration();
```

Comment: This is not the way to get it… I don’t see a way to get from there to the date format of current logger’s appender